# Is there something like Compare-And-Set in Hazelcast cache?

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I need to glue some objects together in cache. I receive these objects from the queue on different hazelcast nodes.

Example.

```
Node 1 receives message "message 1. part 1"
Node 2 receives message "message 1. part 2"

One of the nodes should send to the output full message 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sinedsem, the simplest solution is to do is following:

```
Value oldValue = imap.get(key)
Value newValue = oldValue;
if (newValue == null) newValue = new Value()
//Either set part1 or part 2 depends on the node
newValue.setPart1(part1)
imap.replace(key, oldValue, newValue)
```

You can check this example as well: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#optimistic-locking